# Howto correct reference a .dll to show up in the modules for debugging in vs2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, dll, linker

I have a c# project that calls some functions from a c dll,
the dll functions are called correctly.
The c dll project is added in the solution where also the c# project is located.

When i try to debug into the dll, the breakpoints won´t be reached because
"..no symbols loaded"
I have all the pdb files in the same directory as the dll.

When i start the debugger, and goto the modules tab, the referenced dll dont show up.
Other dlls like mscorlib.dll are there, but not the dll i want to debug.

Debugger settings are on mixed mode, and i unchecked the only debug own code option.

best regards
gobliins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah i just found the last option i did not acivate,
there´s another checkbox underr project tabs
"debug non managed code"

now all dlls show up